# Implicit conversion and operator overloading

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
struct helper {
    template<typename T> helper(T const&);
};

helper operator*(helper const&);

struct A {};

int main() {
    // (1)
    A a;
    sizeof(*a);

    // (2)
    int i;
    sizeof(*i);
}
```

Case (1) compiles fine and I understand that it is using the implicit conversion to the `helper` type and the given operator overload.

For case (2), however, I get a compiler error:

```
invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

Why is the implicit conversion used for type `A` but not for `int`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When no user defined type is involved, any operator is assumed to be a built-in operator. So

```
helper operator*(helper const&);
```

cannot be found for `*i` when `i` is of built-in type (such as `int`).